# Java code downloading data from this url

Tags: java, url, download

So I am new to java programming and I am supposed to download data from the URL below every 5 minute.

host: 204.8.38.210

Get:/Iowa.Sims.AllSites.C2C/IADOT_SIMS_AllSites_C2C.asmx/OP_ShareTrafficDetectorData?MSG_TrafficDetectorDataRequest=string%20HTTP/1.1

I get this error-"Server returned HTTP response code : 400 " using this code below

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class JavaDownload {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String fileName = "file3x.html";

        URL link = new URL("http://204.8.38.210/Iowa.Sims.AllSites.C2C/IADOT_SIMS_AllSites_C2C.asmx/OP_ShareTrafficDetectorData?MSG_TrafficDetectorDataRequest=string%20HTTP/1.1");

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n=0;

        while(-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        {
            out.write(buf,0,n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");

    }

}
```

Comment: Then your URL is wrong (or the server is off), try to access the data manually to check the right URL.

Comment: The code works perfect here (at this moment).

Comment: I am able to manually access the URL manually. This is the full error complain I get:Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://204.8.38.210/Iowa.Sims.AllSites.C2C/IADOT_SIMS_AllSites_C2C.asmx/OP_ShareTrafficDetectorData?MSG_TrafficDetectorDataRequest=string HTTP/1.1
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
 at day1.xmlDownload.JavaDownload.main(JavaDownload.java:16)

Comment: Thanks Gerold and Dici, its working now. I think it was a spacing in the URL..